# How can I use Parcel class to send an object with complex attributes to another activity?

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel

I need to send an object `ModuleDetection` from an activity to another. I've found that using the `Parcel` class to turn my object into a `Parcelable` object would help me. However, in every example I could find, the parcelable object's attributes had default types of Android. But the `ModuleDetection` object has an attribute of `ImageInterface` type, another class that I made.

When writing the method :

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
}
```

I can't use methods like `dest.writeInt()` or `dest.writeString()` , because my attribute hasn't a default type of android. How can I do this?

Comment: Implement Parcelable in both ModuleDetection & ImageInterface. Then you can pass its objects.

Comment: make the other class `Parcelable` as well and use `dest.writeParcelable(Parcelable p, int parcelableFlags)` to write it

Answer (score 1):

You should make both classes implement `Parcelable`. When you pass your `ModuleDetection` object as a parcelable, the `ImageInterface` field will get handled as well.

Answer (score 1):

> You should make both classes implement Parcelable. When you pass your ModuleDetection object as a parcelable, the ImageInterface field will get handled as well.

You can make your ImageInterface extend Parcelable so each ImageInterface implementation will have to implement also parcel

[Here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) is an example